# Enable evil in specific modes

Tags: evil

I want Emacs to default to Emacs bindings, but to be able to define a list of modes in `init.el` that enable `evil-mode`.

I want something similar to this:

http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Evil#Enter_an_emacs_mode_in_a_given_state

but in reverse, where evil is explicitly enabled by mode, rather than Emacs bindings being enabled by mode.

Comment: Have a look at the [Emacswiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil) and scroll down to "Modes' initial state".

Comment: Why?  Evil is specially built to be enabled globally, therefore it allows bypassing its keys by using Emacs state.

Comment: @wasamasa I only like using vim bindings for code editing and a handful of other tasks. I have a snippet in my init.el that disables evil for a number of modes like org-mode, info-mode, diary-mode, dired-mode etc. It's gotten unruly because there are so many modes that I prefer to have the original bindings for.

Answer (score 1):

You can `customize-variable` `evil-default-state` (to `emacs`, `insert` ...)

Comment: This is close to what I want. How would I go about enabling vim bindings for specific modes, like prog-mode? I unsuccessfully tried adding a hook, but my elisp abilities are elementary.

Comment: Didn't [`(evil-set-initial-state …)`](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Evil#Enter_an_emacs_mode_in_a_given_state) work _along_ `evil-default-state`? I don't think you need hooks on this recipe

Answer (score -1):

aren't you looking for normal major mode hooks, such as this one:

`(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'evil-mode)`

...to enable evil mode only when editing python files?

note that you can also use `prog-mode-hook` which is intended to be a catch-all hook for any programming language major mode.

Comment: `evil-mode` is global, so your suggestion will not work.  Neither will using the hook system to enable specific states, as evil is initialized *after* them.

Comment: evil-local-mode?

Comment: That can be used, but will lead to bugs as Evil has been designed to be used as a global minor mode.  Your best bet is to just customize the initial states, really.